# Uneven Sharing in Python Performance Algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

A group of k boys, should be paid marbles as follows: they sit in a circle, and each boy will take 1 marble more than the boy to his right just did, and pass the bag with the remainder of the marbles to the boy on his left.

The leader starts by taking out 1 marble for himself. He passes the bag to the boy on his left, who then removes 2 marbles for himself, and passes the bag to his left. That boy then takes 3 coins and passes the bag on to his left, and so on. This process continues until the bag is empty (the last boy to take from the bag may not get as many marbles as he should).

I want to get the total number of marbles that the LEADER receives at the end of the process.

This is what I have, it works but it is too slow:

```
def countMarbles(n, k):
    c = 0
    leader = 0
    while n>0:
        for i in range(k):
            c+=1
            if i == 0:
                if c<=n:
                    leader += c
                else:
                    leader += n
            n -= c
    return leader
```

Comment: You don’t need to actually loop over `range(k)`, because you can work out a closed form for what will happen to `c`, `n`, and `leader` over those `k` iterations pretty easily. Of course that will fail for the very last loop, but you can detect that—if the new `n` would be negative, just do the round by looping. With your existing code.

Comment: But meanwhile, why are you doing `leader += n` for everyone else’s turns? Doesn’t that mean the leader is going to end up with many times more marbles than there actually are?

Comment: Anyway, once you’ve worked out a closed form for each inner loop but the last, you can work out what would happen from doing `x` loops, and bisect to find the best `x` to leave you as close to `n=0` without going negative. Then just do that, followed by the one remaining partial loop. This won’t as efficient as coming up with a closed-form answer to the entire problem, but it doesn’t require any complicated math, and should be fast enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marbles you are speding are 1, then 2, then 3...
There is a formula for this kind of sum, the sum of 1 to x is `(x)(x + 1) / 2`.

Now you are given n, and want to know how many passes of the bag you can make. This means getting highest x such that `(x)(x + 1) / 2` is lower or equal to n.

We can get this by solving `0 = x^2 + x - 2n`. We might get a decimal result there, so we should take the floor value of the positive answer to the equation.

Once we found the correct x, we just know that every k passes of the bag, 1 goes to the leader. He first gets 1 marble, then he gets k + 1 marbles, then 2k + 1...

If there were x passes, ceil of `x / k` went to the leader. Taking out the first pass which is always 1, we get `l = ceil(x / k) - 1` passes that have a k coefficient greater than 0: `((k + 1) + (2k + 1) + ... + (lk + 1)) = (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + l) * k + l = (l * (l + 1) / 2) * k + l.`

Considering leader started with 1, the solution is `(l * (l + 1) / 2) * k + l + 1`

The only problem is what happens with the remainding marbles that were left in the bag. In the case that those should have gone to leader, we also need to take them into account. For that to happen, x must be a multiple of k, meaning that we finished the round so the next should have been leader, but there were not enough marbles to make another pass.

Here is a python implementation:

```
import math

def solve (n, k):
    x = math.floor((-1 + math.sqrt(1 + 8*n)) / 2)
    l = math.ceil(x / k) - 1
    sol = (l * (l + 1) / 2) * k + l + 1
    if x % k == 0 :
        sol += n - (x * (x + 1) / 2)
    return int(sol)
```

Comment: I get where you are going with the closed form solution but it is quite complex for me to code in python, which is why I used a loop. I am new to this

Comment: @TheNewManInTown had a few bugs, should all be fixed now. Yeah it involves a bit of math, depending of how big is n your solution could work too

Comment: My problem was finding x. Thank you for your help. I understand now